# javascript telephone dialer - keep number within a specific range

Tags: javascript

For example, A var n, **initial value is 0**. When mouse being dragged, decrease n by 1, but keep n between 0 to 11. Think this like the circle-dialer on an old telephone, var n loops between 0-11. I've tried abs, min and max, none of them works. Is there any method to achive this? just point me in a direction or any keywords would be appreciated.

Many thanks.

```
var n =0;
function mouseDragged() {
n-=1; 

console.log(n);
//as long as console.log keeps showing 0-11, the problem is solved
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `mouseDragged` needs a parameter that tells it whether to increment or decrement `n`. In this example, I will pass in a boolean `increment` flag.

```
var n = 0;

function mouseDragged(increment) {
  if (increment) {
    if (n < 11) {
      n += 1;
    }
  } else if (n > 0) {
      n -= 1;
  }
  console.log(n);
}
```

[UPDATE]

On the other hand, if you never want to increment, but you also want to be able to loop around from 0 back up to 11, then this should work:

```
var n = 0;

function mouseDragged() {
  if (n > 0) {
    n -= 1;
  } else {
    n = 11;
  }

  console.log(n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you remind me some idea. I ran the code and var n can just go from 0 to 11, then back and stays at 10, no going back to 0. So I tried to add another var i, which counts how many rounds it runs, and add another condition to check if i/10 is an integer. Thanks. I need to check if there is any eisier way to do this.

Comment: another thing is it must be n-=1, I will try my best not to use n+=1. just need to find  a way to do this without n+=1

Comment: I don't understand your first comment. And your second comment also does not make sense to me. It seems like you want to start `n` at 0, and you only want to allow decrementation of `n`, but you never want `n` to be less than 0. What is the point of the function if it never actually changes anything?

Comment: Ye, it's a bit weird. The first comment means I tried your code, and when I checked console, it only showed me 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 10 10 10 10 10 10.., I thought something might gone wrong, so I tried to add another var i within one of the if() statements, everytime n+=1, do i++, so if(i/10 is an integer) {the statement runs only when i reaches 10, 20,30...}, I am still trying to figure out it works or not. The second comment is exactly what you said, n starts at 0, by decreasing n, make n loops between 0-11, without using n+=1. Only use n-=1.  I tried abs(), min(), max(), etc, failed

Comment: I want the console.log outputs 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1......,  or 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11....

Comment: yep sorry this is a bit weird, if it also makes no sense to other people, it probably is. just to see it's just me or others also find this unsolvable. but thanks for the help